# What is the dual space of the set of all riemann integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration, dual-spaces

I was going through the dual of the basis of a vector space - which is essentially the set of linear functionals such that if $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n\}$ is the basis vectors then $\{f_1,..,f_n\}$ such that $f_i(\alpha_j)=1$ if $i=j$ or $0$ otherwise.
Now I read in Wikipedia which essentially says that dual of anything can be obtained by inverting the conditions (if I understood it correctly)

Now I was wondering will the dual space of all continuous functions,differentiable functions and Riemann integrable functions exist.So will the dual of all Riemann integrable functions be all the differential functions.  If they exist then what are they?

Comment: Things are a bit tricky since you're talking about infinite dimensional spaces. First of all, you'll have to specify whether you're interested in the "algebraic dual space" or "continuous dual space"; typically, people think about the continuous dual space in this context. If you are thinking about the continuous dual, then you'll have to specify what your topology is, i.e. how you measure distance.

Comment: Probably, the simplest way to consider the kind of answer that you're interested in is to consider [the space $L^1([0,1])$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces). This is almost the space that you were asking about except that we have replaced Riemann integrability with Lebesgue integrability. As is stated further down on the linked page, the (continuous) dual space to $L^1([0,1])$ is $L^\infty([0,1])$.